# "One way" level shifter for PWM 4PIN fan control

Tags: pwm, level-shifting, fan

I'd like to make a [4 pin pwm fan control](https://folk.uio.no/kyrrens/diverse/viftekontroller/developer-specs-REV1_2_Public.pdf) using 3v3 uC. Fan is 12v powered and I have a 12v to 3v3 converter to power uC (VCC gate is 3v3 uC power). I want to isolate 3v3 VCC and 12v as much as possible, but without using optocouplers, just with FETs. This fan has a PWM input that shall be used to control it's speed. I need to make some kind of "repeater" for uC 3v3 logical level PWM signal. The output level shall not exceed 5V, so I made the following schematics:

[image: 4-wire PWM Fan Control]

The "highlighted" part is the "repeater". My questions are:

1. Is it ok to use such a repeater?
2. Is it possible to simplify it, for example to make it using just one FET?

Comment: Why do you want to isolate but without an isolator? There's no purpose that repeater is serving. It's not isolating anything. It's just redundant extra parts. Just get rid of both transistors and connect it directly.

Comment: I want to isolate these parts but without optocouplers. I suppose it is possible with fets. Just want to make it simpler

Comment: But WHY? For what purpose? Because it's not protecting anything against anything. MOSFET gates are literally atoms thick and isolate nothing.

Comment: For example, some of my fans are draining power thru pwm control and pwm monitoring pins. Some other sets 5-12 v on these pins. But it is out of the question's scope really. You can just treat it as a theoretical question about electricity.

Comment: @BblkTOP It isn't. This is what we call an XY problem. Are you trying to say that your control signal does not have enough current capability to drive multiple PWM input of the fans and therefore you need a signal buffer?

Comment: I think the OP means "The fan won't pay attention to 3.3v signaling, I need to convert my 3.3V to 12V for the fan."

Comment: @vicatcu Except he uses R1, R3, and R3 to step down the output from Q1 to 4V

Comment: @vicatcu correct, except that according to the specs it shall be up to 5v, not 12v

Comment: @DKNguyen For example, some of my fans are draining power thru pwm control and pwm monitoring pins. Some other sets 5-12 v on these pins.

Comment: @BbIKTOP I think there is a language barrier since I'm not sure what you are trying to say when you say "draining power through PWM pins". So I'm assuming you just need to convert a 3.3V digital signal to 5V digital signal, correct?

Comment: @DKNguyen I mean that in case I connect some of my fans PWM control or PWM monitoring pins directly to the uC GPIO pins, I observe about 2V on the fan's power pins even if the fan is not powered. Fan is trying to rotate making noice and I think at last it will burn either fan or uC. I do not observe such a voltage in case I disconnect PWM pins. But please, how is it related to my question? I always try to keep my questions here as simple as possible to avoid such a discussions ("why do you want to do that? Do you really need to do that?" etc) And as I see I did not succeed. Again )))

Comment: @BbIKTOP Those questions are asked when it looks like you're going about fixing some unknown problem the wrong way.The 2V on the fan is actually expected behaviour due to the ESD protection diodes inside the ICs in the fan's electronics. You can fix that just by placing 1K or 10K resistors in series with the GPIO. You may still see the voltage but it will limit the current so the fan won't be able to do anything to harm itself.

Comment: @DKNguyen I tried different resistors and diode on the PWM monitoring pin as well with no success. It's a really long story, and I want to do that for a reason.

Comment: @BbIKTOP I suggest that you instead of posting about how to do what you're trying to do, and instead post about your actual issue and get help solving it since what you're does not seem like the best go about it.

Comment: Did that, didn't get answers. I believe this will solve any issues by isolating 12v and 3v3 circuits, so no need to investigate why and how these fans are designed and why there's also 9v on the uC gpio. Furthermore, resistors won't work because input resistance of uC gpio is very high, so current is very low and it would not produce any significant voltage dropout. Really, I spent too much time trying to solve it, much simpler just  to use fets with high resistance and forget about that issue

Comment: @DKNguyen you edited your comments ) "MOSFET gates are literally atoms thick and isolate nothing" - the gate-source leakage of the DMN3404L is 100nA - quite good resistance to isolate uC from any unwanted voltage

Comment: @BbIKTOP isolation means something pretty specific in electronics with specific goals which is why a MOSFET gate isnt included in that

Comment: @DKNguyen "Isolation" in electricity means "to reduce current between circuits", ideally to zero. In real apps current can never be reduced to zero, so, the quality of "isolation" is measured by that current, i. e. isolation's resistance. So, from this point of view, this IS the isolation. But ok, could you please suggest me another term to express what I want to do? )))

Comment: @BbIKTOP Well isolation usually implicates some degree of safety which this obviously doesn't do, but it's also not what you were after. Your reasoning about resistors not working because the uC pin being very high resistance contradicts the fan trying to start up when the uC applies a signal with no power to the pin (it implies the uC is low resistance so can push enough power to the fan) which is why I think you're not going about this the right way. You said you believe this will work...you haven't tried it out yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have over designed the circuitry of your PWM driver. This should be all you need:

[image]

I have shown changed values for the resistors in the voltage divider get a full 5V swing of the signal and to speed up the rise time of the PWM to the fan.

**Member Requested Description of Rise Time PWM Distortion**

The following waveform shows a PWM waveform with a lazy rise time in the green color. The horizontal red line shows an example 2.0V threshold voltage of where a fan's internal circuit may detect the level change of the input PWM waveform. The blue colored waveform shows the net high level the fan sees for the PWM input. As can be seen if the rise time of the green waveform were way faster there would be much less distortion of the PWM by the fan. This is further confirmed by the fast falling edges of the waveforms.

[image]

** Comparison of PWM Rise Times (20kHz PWM) **
These first two simulation pictures show the waveforms for the original resistor values in your circuit 20K * 10K. The values which give a 4V PWM swing.

[image]

The following pictures show the modified resistor values that provide for a 5V swing and with improved rise time.

[image]

Comment: In that case the pwm signal will be inverted, isn't it?

Comment: who cares...? it's duty cycle that matters, just flip sense in software

Comment: Lol )))) To be honest, at the beginning I thought about it too. But no, I need "normal" one, not inverting

Comment: @BbIKTOP - Please unstuck your thinking. Any PWM is normal. In this case when you want 20% program 80%; want 45% program 55%.

Comment: I use 3rdparty library and cannot modify it

Comment: Btw, why did you set resistors to the lower value?

Comment: @BbIKTOP - To get the fan PWM signal swing to be 0V to 5V. The lower values also allow for better rise time of the signal. When the resistor values are too high the rise time becomes longer and it distorts the net duty cycle seen by the speed controller chip in the fan.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Could you please tell me more about rising time? don't really understand the dependency

Comment: I'll add a description to the answer above.

Comment: @BbIKTOP - Rise time description added to the answer.

Comment: @MichaelKaras it's clear but I don't understand why with lower resiztors values the rising time will be shorter. As far as I understand, it might me significant in case fets have really high input capacitance, but according to the specs their capacitance is about 500pF which is irrelevant on these voltages. Am I wrong?

Comment: @BbIKTOP - The rising edge is all about capacitance being charged through the upper resistor. The fan input has capacitance, the cable to the fan has capacitance, the circuit on your board has capacitance. I lowered the resistor values based upon my practical experience of years spent designing server computer boards with lots of fan driver circuits on them. You do have to consider the frequency of the PWM waveform. For a given length of rise time the amount of PWM distortion will be way more for a 20kHz PWM that it would be for a 500Hz PWM, In the end (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) you have to decide what is appropriate for your application. I mainly wanted to alert you to the potential issue so you could be knowledgeable about it.

Comment: Added rise time comparison for resistors changes with 200pF capacitance.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Dear Michael, thank you! I appreciate your help so much, as a programmer with a 30+ years experience I appreciate your effort spending your free time to help hobbyists like me. My mistake in that case was that I forgot that pwm is 20kHz and was thinking about 1-2 kHz rotation speed. Sure, in that case you’re completely right. Following your answer - would it be ok also to change dividers to the 1k:3k to reduce the voltage? Do I understand correctly, that lower voltage will be reached faster with the same capacitance?

Comment: @MichaelKaras I accepted your answer although I cannot use it because my original questions were: “will it work?” and “is it possible to make a repeater (level shifter, sorry, I’m not a pro in electronics, do not know the correct term) using 1 fet?” It was obvious that it’s possible to invert the pwm, my very first schematic was exactly like this, but it makes the code unclean and hard to maintain later, for example wiht the libraries (this is my case)

Comment: Btw, there’s an error in the picture, it will newer work this way. I made it on the breadboard first and did a mistake drawing it in the eagle, r4 shall be connected to the 12v, not 3v3 vcc

Comment: @MichaelKaras Michael, I have to admit, you were completely right! I tried R3=510 and R2=2K2 and, as you said, still have about 7-10% duty loss due to the slow rising of the PWM signal. I observe good signal from the uC that becomes slow after fets. Would you suggest anything? I see the simplest way is to return to your first advice and to use "inverted" pwm, although it's a bit complicated in my case. I can ask another question if necessary. Thank you!